# Custom HTML login form in HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: javascript, http-authentication, basic-authentication

I have an API with HTTP Basic Auth. If non-authenticated users send HTTP requests, then the server returns 401 status code and `WWW-Authenticate` header. And browser shows standard login form. Is it possible to show my HTML login form instead of standard browser's login form?

Comment: How is this API requested from the client? Are you using some AJAX call or directly submitting a form or redirecting to the endpoint?

Comment: client sends AJAX requests to the API

Comment: If you are using ajax then probably you should handle the response from server and show login page to user.

Comment: If you use AJAX, then normally the browser will not show the standard login dialog. It would instead return 401 that you could capture in your AJAX call and act accordingly (redirect to your custom login form).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using an AJAX call, you could intercept the 401 status code from the server and redirect the user to a custom login form. For example let's suppose that you were using jQuery and trying to access the protected with Basic Authentication API endpoint https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd',
    type: 'GET'
}).then(function(result) {
    alert('success');
}).fail(function(xhr) {
   if (xhr.status === 401) {
       // we are not authenticated => we must redirect the user to our custom login form
       window.location.href = '/my-custom-login-form';
   }
});
```

Once you have collected the username and password you will know how to construct the correct authentication header on subsequent requests to your API:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd',
    type: 'GET',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd2Q='
    }
})...
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a standard login dialog, because I used xhrFields: { withCredentials: true } option when I sent AJAX